# Kony Platform not regconize Xcode

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am working on the Kony Platform 6.5. My Kony Studio don't recognize my Xcode when I click refresh button in the Preferences. I am using the Xcode 7.1.1 . Can anyone give me some suggestion about this problem ?

[This is my attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGYF1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the latest version of the plugins for Kony Studio und Help -> Check for Updates.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of the plugin for Kony Studio already. But the problem is still there. I click the refresh button and it doesn't recognize my Xcode.Do I need to configure the others ?

Comment: I have it working: http://i.imgur.com/ZNzGlKi.png. What do you have under Help -> About License -> View installed plugins? Maybe also make sure you have the 9.1 emulator and restart the Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in the parellel OS environment ( running visualizer in parallel). 
I tried update plugin from kony. But didn`t work.

Then got solved by turn the Xcode server option on.

From menu, Xcode -> Xcode server.

Please try fetch xcode details after enabling this.